# Proof Verification: Existence of a path $f: [a,b] \to X$ implies the existence of a path $g: [0,1] \to X$.

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Can somebody please tell me if this proof is correct? This is not homework. A wise user told me this result in a previous question and I wanted to prove it before using it. It's a pretty trivial proof, essentially boiling down to the continuity of a polynomial (I'm aware that this is a result from calculus but I didn't want to cut corners). I just made a bunch of particularly stupid mistakes in a proof of a claim related to this and I want to ensure I am not missing anything.

Let $k: [0,1] \rightarrow [a,b]$ be defined by $k(t) = a + t(b-a)$. Let X be a path connected space, and let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow X$ be a path in X from $x_1$ to $x_2$.

Lemma : $k$ is continuous.

Notice that $[0,1]$ and $[a,b]$ are subspaces of the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$, where $d$ is the standard metric for $\mathbb{R}$ (defined by $d(x,y) = |x-y|$). Hence, the restriction $d_1$ of $d$ to $[0,1]$ x  $[0,1]$ is a metric for the subspace topology on $[0,1]$ and the restriction $d_2$ of $d$ to $[a,b]$ x $[a,b]$ is a metric for the subspace topology on $[a,b]$ (proof was done earlier, don't worry).

We first want to show that $k$ is order preserving. This is pretty clear, but fix $x,y \in [0,1]$ s.t. $x < y$. Then, $x(b-a) < y(b-a)$ because $(b-a) > 0$. Then, $a + x(b-a) < a + y(b-a)$ so that $f(x) < f(y)$.

Fix $x \in [0,1]$ and $\epsilon > 0$ (and forget that we previously also fixed y in that interval).

Notice that if $y \in B_{d_1}(x,\frac{\epsilon}{b-a})$, then $d_1(x,y) = d_1(y,x) = |y-x| <\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$. Then, $x - \frac{\epsilon}{b-a} < y < x + \frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$. Notice that $k(x) - \epsilon = a - \epsilon + x(b-a) = a + (x - \frac{\epsilon}{b-a})(b-a) = k(x - \frac{\epsilon}{b-a})$ and $k(x) + \epsilon = a + \epsilon + x(b-a) = a + (x + \frac{\epsilon}{b-a})(b-a) = k(x + \frac{\epsilon}{b-a})$. Then, $k(x) - \epsilon < f(y) < k(x) + \epsilon$ because $f$ is order preserving. That is, $|k(y)-k(x)| = d_2(k(y),k(x)) = d_2(k(x),k(y)) < \epsilon$.

We have shown that if $d_1(x,y) < \frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$, then $d_2(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$. Then, $k$ is continuous by Theorem 21.1. Q.E.D

Claim: If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow X$ is a path in X from $x_1$ to $x_2$, then $f':[0,1] \rightarrow X$ defined by $f'(t) = (f \circ k)(t)$ is also a path in X from $x_1$ to $x_2$.

It is clear that $f'(0) = x_1$ and that $f'(1) = x_2$. Notice that $f'$ is continuous by Theorem 18.2(c) because $k$ is continuous by the lemma and $f$ is continuous by hypothesis. We conclude that $f'$ is a path in X. Q.E.D.

Theorems:

Theorem 21.1: Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$; let X and Y be metrizable with metrics $d_X$ and $d_Y$, respectively. Then continuity of $f$ is equivalent to the requirement that given $x \in X$ and given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ s.t. $$d_X(x,y) < \delta \implies d_Y(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon.$$

Theorem 18.2(c): Let X,Y,Z be topological spaces. If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow Z$ are continuous, then the map $g \circ f: X \rightarrow Z$ is continuous.

If anybody out there notices any mistakes, please tell me (It's getting late so I might have missed something). Any comments or criticisms are also very welcome. Thank you! :)

Comment: It's easier if you argue that $k(t) = a + t(b-a)$ is continous because it's just a linear map and $f \circ k$ is continous since it's a composition of continous functions.

Comment: Good point, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you see something like this, make use of the fact that $[0,1]$ and $[a,b]$ are homeomorphic.  Therefore, maps out of them should act the same way, which is what your problem is getting at.

As the commenter points out, the map $k: [0,1] \to [a,b]$ defined by 
$$
k(t) = a + t(b-a)
$$
is certainly continuous as it is linear.  (It's also a homeomorphism, but you don't need that for your exact question.  I'll come back to this.)  Then given any path $f: [a,b] \to X$ we have the path $g = f \circ k: [0,1] \to X$ as desired, since compositions of continuous maps are still continuous.  (And you said all this.)

Bonus fact:  since $k$ is a homeo, the converse is true by the same argument.  The inverse to $k$ is $h: [a,b] \to [0,1]$ defined by
$$
h(t) = \frac{t-a}{b-a}
$$
(again linear, again continuous).  So the exact same argument shows that every path out of $[0,1]$ gives a path out of $[a,b]$.  In fact, these two "translations of domain" give a bijection between the sets of paths out of these two different (but homeomorphic) domains.  This nice symmetry is a good justification of why the definition of a homeomorphism is **not** as a continuous bijection, but as a continuous bijection with continuous inverse.

Comment: I know I'm not in general supposed to post comments like this, but thank you so much for the detailed comment and, in particular, the bonus fact!! Also, I'm so sorry for not accepting your answer earlier (I forgot to do so after I stopped frequenting the stack exchange).